# How can I figure out the amount of bytes in a Frame?

Tags: yuv, color-space

I want to write a programm which compares the first frame of two given raw files. The files are either in the swapped colorspace I420, I422 or I444.
For the colorspace I know that the size of one frame in bytes is:
bytesPerFrame = int(width * height * 12/8)
I can't find any information on the other two colorspaces which allow me to figure out the amount of bytes used per frame. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.fourcc.org/yuv.php contains a plethora of information regarding most of the YCbCr formats out there. Basically, it all relates to how chroma is subsampled.

**4:2:0**

```
frame_size = width * height * 3 / 2
```

**4:2:2**

```
frame_size = width * height * 2
```

**4:4:4**

```
frame_size = width * height * 3
```